# How to write a lexer/parser for if statements

Tags: python, parsing

Since my past question was not answered, I'll ask a shorter version again:
I need help writing a parser for if statements in Python. For reference, here's an example of if statements in my language:

```
IF 2 > 1 THEN
    OUT "Hello World!" // Print Statement
ENDIF
```

I already parse conditions like this, and they return true or false:

```
elif toks[i] + " " + toks[i+1][0:3] + " " + toks[i+2] + " " + toks[i+3][0:3] + " " + toks[i+4] == "IF NUM EQEQ NUM THEN":
        if toks[i+1][4:] == toks[i+3][4:]:
            print("TRUE, " + toks[i+1][4:] + " is equal to " + toks[i+3][4:])
            return true

            i += 5
        else:
            print("FALSE, " + toks[i+1][4:] + " is not equal to " + toks[i+3][4:])
            return false
```

That was for an equality, by the way. I am thinking of changing this up though and making a condition function then using it in the IF parser. The one problem I have is skipping to the ENDIF statement with the iterator value... Can someone instruct me on how to write an if statement parser in python, minus the conditions?

Comment: Have you looked to the actual python source? https://www.python.org/downloads/source/

Comment: in an effort to not give away the fun of implementation, I urge you to look into an algorithm called the "Shunting yard algorithm" created by Dijkstra. Couple this with binary tree construction (I'll let you figure your way to evaluating a binary tree of operations). This will be the easiest for simple language implementations and for learning.

Comment: I'm [writing a language too](https://github.com/kms70847/KevinScript)! In my case, I wrote an [LR parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser), which is nice because it can understand arbitrarily complex expressions like `if(1 > 2 and 3 < 4 and 5 + 6 * 7 >= f(8,9,10))`. But if you're happy with limiting your conditionals to single operand-operator-operand triples, you could probably get away with a simple [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone!

Comment: Lexing and parsing are really complicated topics. You should really dive into the links @Kevin provided. There is a ton of [pre-existing literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools). You don't want to invent this stuff yourself. For instance, dig into recursive descent parsing and the concept of **grammars**. That'll help you separate the parsing of IF/THEN/ENDIF from the parsing of the conditional expression.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I am well aware of that:) Thanks to everyone, I will be looking over these as soon as I get out of class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! 
While it is very primitive and doesn't support nesting (yet), I have a simple solution to my problem. Basically, whenever it detects the 'IF' token, it loops through all of the tokens after that until it finds and 'ENDIF' token. While doing that, it increments an iterator called 'ii' and at the end, sets the main iterator past the 'ENDIF', ignoring the code within the if statement. This is only done if the condition parser returns false.

code:

```
def doIF_FALSE(tokens):
    ii = 0
    for token in tokens:
        if token == "IF":
            ii = 1
        elif token == "ENDIF":
            ii += 1
            break
        else:
            ii += 1
    return ii
```

for the call, I set the iterator value like this: `i = doIF_FALSE(tokens[i:])`

Example code:

```
IF 1 > 2 THEN
     OUT "1 is greater than 2"
ENDIF

OUT "You passed the if statement"
```

Output:

```
"You passed the if statement"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
elif toks[i]+" "+toks[i+1][0:3]+" "+toks[i+2][0:4]+" "+toks[i+3][0:3]+" "+toks[i+4][0:4]=="IF NUM EQEQ NUM THEN":
    if toks[i+1][4:]!=toks[i+3][4:]:
        print("false")
        break
    i+=5
```

Comment: Can you add a short description?